# Firebase admin SDK failed to decode id token

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm a novice here and this is my first question. I'm making an API with Typescript and Express that connects to my local DB and want to authenticate the user with firebase. I read the instructions on their docs and think I'm doing what they asked, setting up the service account and admin SDK.

When I console the token on client and server side, I get the same token, but I keep getting this error:

```
FirebaseAuthError: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\coisas\nlw\node\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:44:28)
    at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\coisas\nlw\node\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:90:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (C:\coisas\nlw\node\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:149:16)
    at C:\coisas\nlw\node\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\token-verifier.js:138:23
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  errorInfo: {
    code: 'auth/argument-error',
    message: 'Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.'
  },
  codePrefix: 'auth'
```

Here's what I'm trying to do client side (mixin for a Vue app):

```
fetchPedidos: async function (parametros) {
  return axios.get(parametros.endpoint, {
    params: {
      filter: parâmetros.filter || "",
        page: parâmetros.page || 0,
        size: parâmetros.size || 25,
        sort: parâmetros.sort || "",
        codCliente: parametros.codCliente || "",
        codPedido: parametros.codPedido || "",
        token: await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      }
    });
} (the then and catch are elsewere on the app)
```

And Here is the server side, a middleware function for express:

```
export async function firebase_auth(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const token = JSON.stringify(req.query.token)
  console.log(token);
  try {
    const _decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
    return next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(401).json({
      mensagem: "Erro na autenticação do usuário",
      erro: error
    });
  }
}
```

Like I said before, that console.log on the server-side prints the same token that leaves the site, but the admin sdk throws this error saying it can't decode. What am I doing wrong here?

I've looked some similar questions but couldn't get it to work.

*Edit:
The console.log(req.query):
[Powershell print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCkrY.png)

As for the parser, I have this in my server.ts:

```js
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

*Edit 2:
Turns out I shouldn't be using stringify for this, and instead just specify that I want the token as a string in the function call. Thanks @Dharmaraj and @samthecodingman for clarifying this for me!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the error print in the post, but I've made an edit

Comment: Instead of `const token = JSON.stringify(req.query.token)` can you try `const {token} = req.query` and then pass it into verifyIdToken?

Comment: But then I get a typescript error saying that I cant pass Undefined to verifyIdToken()

Comment: I agree with Dharmaraj, as token is a JWT string similar to `abcde.abcde.abcde`, calling `JSON.stringify` will incorrectly add quotes around it which will lead to the error.

Comment: Try this `verifyIdToken(token as string)`. Now typescript will treat it as string. Before that line check if token is defined. `if (!token) return res.sendStatus(401)`

Comment: Also, if TypeScript complains about a type, it's best to add some code to handle those incorrect types rather than simply ignoring them. One such way would be to send back a `400 Bad Request` using `if (token === undefined) { res.status(400).send("token is missing"); return; }` or `if (typeof token !== "string") { res.status(400).send("token is malformed"); return; }`

Comment: Didn't know about the `as string` part, guess I'm just noob at typescript still.

Comment: So is the issue resolved?

Comment: It was the stringify, removed it and now it works, thanks to you and @Dharmaraj!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I shouldn't be using stringify for this, and instead just specify that I want the token as a string in the function call. Thanks @Dharmaraj and @samthecodingman for clarifying this for me!